# Can Dark Matter be...(massive) gravitons?

Tags: particle-physics, universe, quantum-gravity, dark-matter, modified-gravity

The dark matter particle has NOT been found. Despite the quantity of models, I wonder if dark matter could be some (exotic) type of (interacting) gravitons. Is that possible?

Comment: "Massive graviton" is an oxymoron: a graviton is, by definition, a massless helicity-2 particle. Are you perhaps asking whether dark matter could be a massive spin-2 particle? If so, you shouldn't call such a particle a graviton.

Comment: related: [Dark matter: degrees of freedom](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39355/84967).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Not sure where you're getting that "massive graviton" is an oxymoron; it's used in the literature all the time in the same sense that it's used here, especially when talking about things like bigravity. See e,g, https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.06704

Comment: No oxymoron. If you have 8 different gluons (of course we could discuss if they are the same gluon), they are all charged spin 1 particles under strong force (color force). We don't know what is the true nature of quantum gravity...Why not different spin 2 massless states, with one of those states charged under a non-SM force? I see no contradiction in this idea. Of course, massive gravitons are studied in the literarture (KK states, bigravity, etc...). But my question go beyond...What if gravity behaves as dark matter because of some missing quantum number OR non-linear gravitons?

Comment: DM has not been found *yet*.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6561/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Go an Google dRGT massive gravity, that will give you a good idea of a how a massive gravity theory can modify gravity at large distances.

Answer (score 2):

At a very basic level, it won't work. If gravity has a mass $m$, it has an effective range $\frac{\hbar}{mc}$, similar to the weak interaction. This effective range must be at least the scale of the largest galaxy clusters that we observe since they are gravitationally interacting. However, the effective range is (up to a factor of $2\pi$) also the Compton wavelength of the dark matter and so we cannot confine gravitons at scales smaller than this. This might barely be viable if all galaxies were the same size and we had no other measurements of dark matter (it would be the [fuzzy dark matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_cold_dark_matter) case) but because we observe the need for dark matter on a variety of astrophysical scales (from hundreds of pc for the smallest dwarfs to Gpc for the largest galaxy clusters) it just won't work: the smallest dwarf galaxies require a graviton mass large enough that we would simply not observe gravity at the scale of the largest objects.

There are more formal reasons you would not think this would work in quantum field theory at all though. A massless spin-2 boson in 4 spacetime dimensions has 2 helicity states, $j=\pm 2$. A massive one has $5$, $j=2,1,0,-1,-2$. This alone tells you that they are quite different; you cannot simply add a mass to gravity in quantum field theory without also adding additional degrees of freedom. If your theory has a high-energy limit where the fields are approximately massless, you should instead describe the theory in terms of a massless spin-2 boson and $3$ additional degrees of freedom. If your theory does not have a massless limit, we would think of it as an effective theory where the cutoff is comparable to the mass scale in question (for example due to an infinite tower of higher mass states), and you would then seek to UV complete it, and we would expect many more states which are quite light compared to even neutrinos. Additionally, there are fairly strong arguments that any quantum field theory with a weakly interacting massless spin $2$ boson is not fundamental (in the sense that it must be an effective theory with cutoff that scales as the mass); see e.g. [1708.05716](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.05716) (but note that there is a possible, if rather unusual, exception pointed out there).

While people do study so-called massive gravity, it is either in the context of classical field theory (which obviously cannot be a complete description), or a fairly pathological quantum field theory which seems to probably only be valid in the linearized regime and in any case does not explain dark matter.

Comment: This is not quite correct. For example dRGT massive gravity is a non-pathological quantum theory of gravity in the sense that it doesn't have ghost modes. Furthermore, this theory does modify gravity at large distances in a consistent way.